# How to keep singles values in a Column with SQL with a certain fields combination

Tags: sql, sql-server

Given the following table with Customer, Category, Product, Date and Value,

```
Customer | Category | Product | Date | Value | Single value
------------------------------------------------------------
Cust A   | Categ A  | SKU A   |010101|  100  |    100
------------------------------------------------------------
Cust A   | Categ A  | SKU B   |010101|  100  |   
------------------------------------------------------------
Cust A   | Categ B  | SKU C   |010101|  99   |    99
------------------------------------------------------------
Cust A   | Categ B  | SKU D   |010101|  99   |
```

How can I fill the 'Single Value' column, keeping only one value for the combination of a certain key (like Customer,Category, Date)?

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. We need some details here to be able to provide an answer. What you have posted is extremely unclear. Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: what if the single value column had more than 1 unique value for this grouping? Which would you choose?

Comment: So for every unique combination of `Customer`, `Category`, and `Date`, you want a single value?  If you have two rows that share the same customer, category and date, which single value should be displayed?  Can you post your intended output?

Comment: Desired result?

Answer (score 0):

Going out on a limb... here's a way using a `CTE` which you can modify to do what you want. This sets the `[Single value]` column to the `MAX()` value for the paring you described, as highlighted in the `partition by` statement.

```
;WITH CTE AS
(   SELECT  Customer, 
            Category, 
            Date,
            [Single value],
            MAX([Single value]) over(partition by Customer, Category, Date) as NewVal
    FROM    SomeTable
)

UPDATE  CTE
SET     [Single value] = NewVal
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
    update t set t.[Single value]=t.[Value] from 
    (
       select *,row_number()over(partition by Customer,Category, Date order by getdate()) as rn from #t
    ) as t where t.rn=1
```